# JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR in PHP

Tags: php, json, control-characters

I have a large json file about 200 MB in size.
I get a `PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in` error when I convert this file to a php array and read its data, and I get a `JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR` error when I check the syntax of this file.

How can I fix this error?

I used the following code so that I might be able to fix this error, but this also did not work.

```
    $file = fopen("d_1.json","a");
    foreach(file("c_1.json") as $line) {

        fwrite($file,iconv(mb_detect_encoding($line, "auto"), "UTF-8", $line));

    }
    fclose($file);
```

I searched the internet a lot but could not find the right answer.

Comment: I think your JSON string is garbled or not made with the correct UTF-8 encoding. Try to get a valid JSON. A subsequent repair such as removing control characters with preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\ x7F]/', '', $ str); rarely leads to success.

Answer (score 0):

Try to decode JSON with UTF8 flags (PHP >= 7.2)

```php
$json = file_get_contents('c_1.json');
$array = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE);
// or
$array = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE);
```

Comment: PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Comment: `PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in` is array related warning, not json. It's happends when you use array index that does not exists